# Bash: Grab part of string from a command line output

Tags: bash, awk, grep, gawk, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am running a command in CentOS that gives me an output of a string and I want to grab a certain part of that output and set it to a variable.

I run the command ebi-describe-env.

My output as follows:

```
ApplicationName | CNAME | DATECreated | DateUpdated | Description | EndpointURL |   
EnvironmentID | EnvironmentName | Health | Stack | Status | TemplateName | 
Version Label --------------------------
Web App | domain.com | 2012-02-23 | 2012-08-31 | |
anotherdomain.com | e-8sgkf3eqbj | Web-App-Name | Status | 
Linux | Ready | N/A | 20120831 - daily
```

I want to grab the '`20120831 - daily`' part of the string (this string will always change but stays in the same place) and set it to a variable.

Originally I thought I could use grep or sed and print a line after each '|' and set the 13th line to a variable.

I'm very new to bash scripting, so any help would be great. Thank you.

Comment: Is that all supposed to be on one line?

Comment: Yes, it is supposed to be on one line.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F"|" '{print $NF}'
```

this will work:

```
echo " Web App | domain.com | 2012-02-23 | 2012-08-31 | | anotherdomain.com | 
       e-8sgkf3eqbj | Web-App-Name | Status | Linux | Ready | N/A | 
       20120831 - daily" | awk -F"|" '{print $NF}'
```

and yield:

```
20120831 - daily
```

*To assign to a variable* (`data.txt` contains your string just for simplicity, it also works the `echo` above):

```
$ myvar=$(awk -F"|" '{print $NF}' data.txt)
$ echo $myvar
20120831 - daily
```

*Explanation*

the `-F` sets the input field separator, in this case to `|`. `NF` is a built-in `awk` variable that denotes the number of input fields, and the `$` in front of the variable accesses that element, i.e., in this case the last field in the line (`$NF`).

*Alternatively*: You could grab each of the last three fields separated by white space (the `awk` default) with this:

```
awk '{print $(NF-2), $(NF-1), $NF}'
```

Comment: @MichaelLe Updated the answer to show the assignment to a shell variable

Comment: @MichaelLe Happy to have been able to help.

Comment: I realized that I had a larger output and formatted my original question. I tried using $(NF-1) and such to grab the next fields, but it turns out that it is on the incorrect line. How would I go to the next line in the output? Thank you.

Comment: @MichaelLe That's a very different problem and really merits its own new question. It's one thing to grab part of a line (which is what you asked for originally) and then to have a different problem that consists of a multi-line (always? sometimes?) input where parts you are interested in are on potentially different lines (if I understood your comment). I would suggest you accept an answer that solved the problem you posted, and then carefully formulate another separate question to post new (including accurate input data and desired output). AWK, like other solutions here, is line-oriented.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize that there was more effort because it was multiline.

Comment: @MichaelLe No problem. When you post your new question it will be helpful if you can provide sample input and output. I'm sure the SO community will be able to help.

Answer (score 3):

Levon's answer works great, but I just had to show there are always other ways with shell scripting.

This one uses the basic tool called `cut`

```
echo "Web App | domain.com | 2012-02-23 | 2012-08-31 | | anotherdomain.com |  e-8sgkf3eqbj | Web-App-Name | Status | Linux | Ready | N/A |   20120831 - daily" | cut -d"|" -f13
```

Comment: Can you explain what the -f13 does?

Comment: If you have access to a Unix/Linux/*nix box, pull up a terminal and type `man cut`.  In short, the `-d"|"` indicates that the `|` symbol separates fields, and the `-f13` part asks for the 13th field.

cut -d"|" -f13

Answer (score 0):

I know that this has been accepted already, but here's how to do it in pure bash:

```
string="Web App | domain.com | 2012-02-23 | 2012-08-31 | | anotherdomain.com | e-8sgkf3eqbj | Web-App-Name | Status | Linux | Ready | N/A | 20120831 - daily"
myvar="${string##*| }"
echo "$myvar"
```

Comment: Is there a reason to avoid Awk in this case? Awk is specified by POSIX and provided by Busybox. Smaller embedded systems don't have it, maybe? This is not a rhetorical question.

Comment: @ngks No, I just felt like pointing out that bash's internal string constructs are up to this particular job.

Comment: Cool, as @Levon said there are always other ways.