# Bash: Grabbing output of command line program execution and setting to variable

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, awk, centos, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am running a command in CentOS that gives me an output of a multiple line string and I want to grab a certain part of that output and set it to a variable.

For example I run the commandline

```
ebi-describe-env
```

My output as follows:

```
ApplicationName | CNAME | DATECreated | DateUpdated | Description | EndpointURL |   
EnvironmentID | EnvironmentName | Health | Stack | Status | TemplateName | 
Version Label -------------------------------------
Web App | domain.com | 2012-02-23 | 2012-08-31 | |
anotherdomain.com | e-8sgkf3eqbj | Web-App-Name | Status | 
Linux | Ready | N/A | 20120831 - daily
```

I want to grab the '20120831-daily' part of the multi-string which is in the same place every call and set it to a variable. I believe the '------' means a new line or output.

I'm very new to bash scripting, so any help would be great. Thank you.

Note: I asked the question before and it was solved with awk, but it turned out it was only for a one line output.
[Previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12223615/bash-grab-part-of-string-from-a-command-line-output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
dateStr=$( ebi-describe-env | grep "Linux | Ready" | cut -t"|" -f4 )
```

Run the command and pipe its output through `grep`, which will only pass lines (well, the line) that contain the string "Linux | Ready". This is then passed to cut, which treats "|" as a delimiter and only prints the 4th field. The output is then captured by the `$(...)` construct and assigned to the variable `dateStr`.

Slightly better is Ben Jackson's `awk` solution, which can replace my `grep/cut` combination:

```
dateStr=$( ebi-describe-env | awk -F"|" 'NR==6 {print $NF}' )
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily add a pattern to match a particular line to the previous answer:

```
awk -F"|" 'NR == 6 {print $NF}'
```

The "pattern" for a block in `awk` can be any conditional.  In my example `NR` is the line number, so that prints the last (pipe-separated) word on line 6.  You could also use a pattern like `/Linux/` if you want the line that has "Linux" in it.